# SSMS Object Explorer

Tags: ssms

Was wondering if anyone can help but I downloaded the latest version of SSMS and there isn't an object explorer. Even in the view panel there isn't any. Does anyone know if there's a fix? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From this link https://www.microsoft.com/tr-tr/sql-server/sql-server-downloads you can download SQL server 2019 installation server from there click on Maintenance and Click on repair.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).